# how to test .net webservice in java when .Net service is not available

Tags: java, .net, web-services, testing, reverse-engineering

I have just a .net wsdl file and I want to connect to it using java to test some functionalities.

But the problem is that I have just access to .Net server in production environment! and I can not connect to it at work!!!

I'm thinking of a way to reverse engineer the wsdl file and generate java class from that, then I can create another web service in java that is exactly like .Net web service and run my program and test it using java.

Do you know any tool or command to reverse engineer a .net web service to java class?
I've heard of SOAPUI, does that have such a feature?

**EDIT :**

By the way I'm using jax-ws (the reference implementation of java webservice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you can do is:

1) create a Maven project

2) add the [cxf-codegen-plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) to the pom.xml file

3) the plugin generates a Java interface, along with classes needed for SOAP communication

4) create a class which implements the interface (provided you know the logic behind each method)

5) you now have a web-service in Java which does the same thing as the .net counterpart

6) deploy to an app server like Glassfish/Tomcat/etc

5) ???

6) profit

Comment: Thanks alegen, but this plugin will generate the client artifacts that is usable to call the webservice. I need a tool that reverse the wsdl to get the code that has created this wsld. the file that has   my `@WebMethod` method.

Comment: the WSDL file does not contain any logic related to implementation. you cannot 'reverse' a WSDL file, i don`t understand what you are trying to get out of it... if you want C#/Java/etc code **with implemented methods** from the WSDL file that is just not possible

Comment: yes I know that wsdl does not represent the implementation of methods;) I mean by `code` is the java interface. does this maven plugin give me that interface? just method signatures!

Comment: it gives a proper `interface` with `annotations` and everything, including classes for objects used as parameters; basically all you have to do is `implement` the `interface` and add logic for the methods... you cannot get more than this out of a WSDL

Answer (score 0):

An appropriately written web service shouldn't care what language the client or server is written in to perform its function.  Just point a utility such as [wscompile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/jaxrpc/jaxrpc-tools.html) at the wsdl and given the right parameter combination it will generate class stubs for you.